# adding large file url to database is taking too much time

Tags: asp.net, iis-express

I'm taking video's url by FileUpload control in Asp .Net .Then I add this url to database for retrieving another asp .net web page. My problem is when I take picture url same way it takes short time but when I take video's url to store in database is taking too much long time and operation become fail without any error message. I guess problem comes from IIS but I don't know how to solve.
I use this code in web.config file.

```
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" maxRequestLength="1048576" executionTimeout="3600"/>
```

Comment: how do you add to the database? show the code. my guess is the video url is too long, it is longer than the field.

Comment: I debug the code, it is not entered the database code. length of video url is same as image url. table for video and image is same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem with change the web.config file like below:

```
 <security>
    <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="1073741824" />
    </requestFiltering> 
 </security>
```

maxAllowedContentLength="1073741824" --> this refer to 1GB file size.